# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django' while running manage.py

Tags: django, python-3.x, windows, virtualenv

I have installed virtualenv and then installed django in my Windows 10. After activating virtualenv and running: `python manage.py runserver`, I am getting:

```
File "manage.py", line 10, in main
from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available
on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual
environment?
```

Also just found while running `django-admin.exe` I am getting:

```
Note that only Django core commands are listed as settings are not properly
configured (error: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not
configured. You must either define the environment variable
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing
settings.).
```

Manage.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Django's command-line utility for administrative tasks."""
import os
import sys


def main():
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'wordcount.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Have you installed `django` inside your virtualenv?

Comment: i have done pip3 install for both virtualenv and django inside the same path under Scripts folder of python...

Comment: Run `pip3 freeze` or `pip freeze` on terminal inside virtual environment.It will list the packages installed. Check if django is in that list.

Comment: yes django 2.2 is there

Comment: I would advice to add the code inside `manage.py` into your question. It will increase the chance to receive help plus reduce the chances to get your story flagged and closed.

Answer (score 0):

You can verify whether you have installed django by creating a python program and importing django

```
import django 
print (django.VERSION)
```

Above code will print the django version installed , confirm whether you have installed django

Comment: i have installed django2.2 using pip also verified using pip freeze

Comment: did you try python3 manage.py runserver, and check for python version you are using , you will have one main version and one more for virtual env , check the version you are using in virtualenv as well as normal shell

Comment: python3 is showing as not recognized I have only python.exe inside the virtualenv

Comment: why dont't you try the troubleshooting , use the code both in virtual env and normal shell , check the results

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 Python versions : The main one which is installed by default and the one used by virtualenv.

When you run `pip install django` Django is installed in the main version of Python and thats because the PYTHONPATH environment variable refers to path of the main version and not virtualenv.

The same thing happens when you run `python manage.py runserver`. It doesn't run python from the virtualenv.

To solve this you need to access pip from the virtualenv and then you can insall Django with it

```
C:\the\path\to\virtualenv\path\to\pip.exe install django
```

And just like pip, run python.exe from virtualenv

```
C:\the\path\to\virtualenv\path\to\python.exe manage.py runserver
```

If you are using PyCharm for development then you can easily set your venv as interpreter.

Now to run django and just like pip you will access python from virtualenv

1 - File > Settings > Your Project > Python Interpreter

2 - Click the settings icon at the right and then click on Add

3 - Click on Virtualenv Environment and choose the location

[image]

[image]

[image]

Once the virtualenv has been setup you can easily use PyCharm to manage packages

[image]

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'C:\\Users\\Roshan\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\Scripts\\django-admin'

Comment: My virtualenv path is in my home dir.

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'C:\\Users\\Roshan\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\Scripts\\django-admin'